# jQuery FullCalendar > How to add a button (or div) to each day?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'd like to give my users the ability to add an event to a jQuery fullCalendar by clicking a small plus (+) at the bottom-right of each day (in month view). What's the best way to achieve this?

One hack-ish way I've found is to assign a `background-image` to `td.fc-widget-content` with `background-position: bottom right` and then using the `dayClick` callback. However, this will break as soon as I want to add one more button to each cell.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Add the Add Event button to eventAfterAllRender. See below:

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view){
    if(view.name == 'month')
    {                       
        $('.fc-day').each(function(){
            $(this).css('position','relative');
            $(this).append('<a class="add_event_label" `enter code here`style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;display: block;border-top:1px solid black;font-size:12px;color:#000;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;">(+)Add Event</a>');
        });      
    }                   
}
```

Comment: Good call - viewDisplay is deprecated in favor of viewRender

Comment: This is a good answer, the problem I'm having now is when there are more than four events on a day in month view, the add_event_label object is hidden or overlapped by evens and I can't seem to get it to show above the other elements.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can add a div/button on top of day boxes, by prepending them to `$(".fc-day-number")` (or in the `<div>` that contains them), handling the insertion in `viewDisplay`...

Comment: No, just do it in the `viewDisplay` callback. Simple test: add this there `$(".fc-day-number").prepend("(+) ");`.

Answer (score 0):

My full solution - places the add event button in the fc-day-number container (at the top of the day container, above and not obstructed by the events):

```
$('#calendar-bsr').fullCalendar({
  eventSources: [
     // event source data, local or remote
  ],
    header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          eventLimit: true,
          eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) {
                eventMove(event.id, event.start.format());
            },
          eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
           //what should happen when event is clicked   
         },
          viewRender: function(view){
            if(view.name == 'month') {
                var add_button = '<a class="add_event_label">+</a>'; 
                $(".fc-day-number").prepend(add_button);
          }

});

// when user clicks the add event, plus button - I load an add event modal
$( "#calendar-bsr" ).on( "click", ".fc-day-number a.add_event_label", 
    function() {
        var dt = $(this).parent().attr('data-date');
      $.ajax({
          url: '/appointments/formbasic',
          type: "get",
          data: {'_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(), 'date': dt },
          success: function(data){
            $("#addmodalTitle").html('Add Milestone on ' + dt );
            $('#newCalModal').modal('show');
            $('#appointment_at').val(dt);
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(data)
          {
           console.log(data);
      }
    });

  });
```